# Local X from FOR to event

Tags: java, javafx

i have problem here : `w = st.getREFkartaFalse(x).getHodnotaKarty();` 
Error : `local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final`

is there any way take value from local x into event ?

```
else if (st.getHracTrueAleboHracFalse() == false) {
        for (int x = 0; x < st.getHracFalse().size(); x++) {
            getChildren().remove(st.getKartaHracFalse(x));
        }
        st.zoberKartuFalse();
        for (int x = 0; x < st.getHracFalse().size(); x++) {
        final int offsetx = 80;
        st.getREFkartaFalse(x).setTaleboF(false);
        st.getKartaHracFalse(x).setTranslateX((400 + (offsetx * x)));
        st.getKartaHracFalse(x).setTranslateY((780));
        getChildren().addAll(st.getKartaHracFalse(x));
        st.setPomPocitadloFalse(x);
        st.getKartaHracFalse(x).setOnMousePressed(eventUI -> {
           int q;
           int w;
           q = st.getArrayListkartyArrayList().size();
           w = st.getREFkartaFalse(x).getHodnotaKarty();
           if (w == q) {

           }
         });
      }
                    st.setHracTrueAleboHracFalse(true);
}
```

Comment: You could create a new variable called `finalX` and initialize it with the value of `x`. Now your lambda function can reference `finalX` without problems.

Comment: Why are you calling `st.getKartaHracFalse(x)` so many times? Can it return different values for the same value of x?

Comment: @FredK because 1st time it give me 7 secound time it give me 12 and third 4 depends on FOR :) and others atributs in my program :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You have to capture the value of `x` in a local (implicitly) final variable:

```
...
st.setPomPocitadloFalse(x);
int y = x;  // <=========================== Capture value of x
st.getKartaHracFalse(x).setOnMousePressed(eventUI -> {
     int q;
     int w;
     q = st.getArrayListkartyArrayList().size();
     w = st.getREFkartaFalse(y).getHodnotaKarty(); // <========  use here
     if (w == q) {

     }
 });
```

Comment: It would be preferable for the sake of clarity and maintainability to really make `y` final: `final int y = x;`. This way you don't have to read the rest of the scope to confirm the variable is (effectively) final and should someone try to modify `y`, you'd get a compiler complaint at source of the problem, not where the "symptoms" show up.